# Where to download free transport and urban data for the capital cities in South East Asia (ASEAN)?

Tags: data, transportation, asia, cambodia

I'm currently looking for the **transport** (mainly public transport - rout lines and stop locations) and **urban** (public amenities, population density etc) data on the capital cities in **South East Asia** (**ASEAN** Region). 
Any idea where I might find them?

Comment: I think this may be a question more suited to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange but, if you decide to post there, then be sure to read what is on-topic for them first.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Cambodia in the tag, you can find what you want from OpenStreetMap (OSM). The data can be downloaded from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/cambodia.html), and you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html) on how to search and download OSM from inside QGIS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used #Cambodia only because of the unavailability of other tags. In fact, I rather need the data on all capital cities in the region.
OSM was my first destination. From what I have seen so far, it seems that the transport-related data are in some cases incomplete, for example the data on Bangkok (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bangkok) doesn't contain any bus-related information. 
I was wondering whether there exist any transport-data specific provider for this region.

Comment: forwarded to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7601/11123